# Block some public/external ip address to connect on internet (from batch file, windows, firewall)

Tags: batch-file, ip, block, ping, windows-firewall

I use Windows 7 Ultimate like Os i searching solution for this Os.

I using a vpn connection I need to block some public/external ip address to access on internet (i need a ping failed) but I do not find any solution.

For public/external ip address I mean the ip address assigned from my isp or my vpn service and it is showed in site like www.mioip.it or whoer.net.

With a bat file I can have the public/external ip address but I do not find solution to create a list of ip address not allowed to access on internet and can give failed the ping (because these ip are not allowed to connect on internet).

I need to block some public/external ip address because if the connection internet not works my software change in automatically the ip address and test it by ping site, if ping failed disconnect and reconnect my adsl automatically and assigned a new public/external ip address.

Before reply try to understand what is a public/external ip otherwise you will give invalid answers.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Ever thought about using the HOSTS file? If not it sounds like `netsh advfirewall /?` Might help you.

Comment: I tryed with windows firewall but i can't block my ip assigned by isp or vpn, with firewall I can block domain ip address (ex. the ip address of facebook domain), I need to block my vpn ip address assigned in a moment.

Comment: You could also add the IP to a bad route.  Something like `route ADD 172.16.0.5 0.0.0.0 IF 1` where `172.16.0.5` is the IP you want to block.  The `IF 1` part means loopback interface.  When you want to delete the bad route, you'd `route DELETE 172.16.0.5 0.0.0.0 IF 1`.  Changes do not persist through reboots unless you include the `-p` switch.

Comment: None of this solutions works, read the question please and do not reply with solution for other functions, thanks

Comment: @placidomaio your question is unclear since you're using vague terminology. Please think carefully about the exact purpose of your question and clearly and concisely update your question. Are you trying to prevent incoming or outgoing connections? Are you trying to block access to your own modem from your computer? Are you trying to avoid being assigned specific IP addresses from your ISP? Some of these can be helped with a firewall. Others can't.

Comment: @shawn I visit this site www.mioip.it or www.whoer.net and i look my ip address public on internet (the ip address that websites saved when I go on internet). Now I'd like to block the connection internet of some ip adress. If in this moment I have ip address 1.2.3.4 (i look it on www.mioip.it) and i decide to block ip address 1.2.3.4 from this time if I have this ip i can not go on internet, the internet connection must deny access me because i have an ip address blocked. If i have ip addres 1.2.3.5 i can go on internet because 1.2.3.5 is not in ip address blocked. Thanks to all for help

Comment: That isn't the way it works. That IP isn't something the websites "save" about you, it's the public IP address that was assigned by your ISP for your connection. Blocking that IP from your computer will have no effect. Your computer doesn't use that address directly. It uses an internal IP address assigned by your modem or router. That internal IP address isn't exposed outward and your public IP isn't exposed inward (unless your network is specifically configured to, which is very unlikely). If you want to temporarily prevent access then you can disable the network adapter instead.

Comment: @shawn Thank you, for this I wrote that all the proposed solutions do not work in my case, I tried them but did not take effect. but the users continued to propose the same solutions that I have already tried and do not work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to block your computer from accessing a website? You can use this file: "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

The usage of this file is redirecting website linkage. Like if you want to go to Google, it redirects your computer to StackOverflow if you have the correct settings. By typing in an non-existing IP, the computer will be directed to a non-existing location so it returns a "no connection" error.

Hope [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) helps.

If you are trying to use a batch file, remember to run the batch file `as Administrator`, or else you may not do any change on that file, unless you have edited its properties.

Comment: This solution is wrong, i need to block public ip of vpn not ip domain, hosts is for manage websites ip address not for public ip (vpn in my case).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an IP address to the Windows firewall with [`netsh advfirewall firewall`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947709/how-to-use-the-netsh-advfirewall-firewall-context-instead-of-the-netsh):

```
 netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block VPN IP" dir=in  action=block enable=yes profile=any localip=any remoteip="8.8.8.8" interfacetype=any
 netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block VPN IP" dir=out action=block enable=yes profile=any localip=any remoteip="8.8.8.8" interfacetype=any
```

Comment: This solution do not work with public ip address, it works only with ip domain, i'm searching how block public ip (example the ip showed in www.mioip.it).

Comment: No, this is the method used to block a public IP address using the windows firewall. What it sounds like you might be trying to ask is how to force your own network to obtain a new IP lease from your ISP. How to do that will depend upon your ISP and your network hardware. Changing the MAC address or restarting the modem/gateway will usually work. Unless you're not using a modem/gateway, blocking any IP from your windows computer will have no effect at all. If you're using a PPPoE connection from Windows then you'd be better off restarting that connection.

Comment: None of this solutions works, read the question please and do not reply with solution for other functions, thanks

Comment: Your question is asking how to block an IP. There is now more than one answer here that provide solutions to that request. If you believe these are incorrect you will need to revise your question, providing explicit examples of your goals since it appears that they are not what you've asked above.

Comment: All these solution are for domain ip only, there are not any solution for ip public/external that assigned by the isp and windows can not know. i'm not interested to block domain ip, i'm interested to block only some ip assigned by my provider and windows can not this because windows do not know the ip assigned from internet provider. ip public/external change some times everyday, if the connection down the public/external ip automatically change. I look here only wrong solution for domain ip and nothing about public/external ip that windows do not know because is assigned by provider adsl

Comment: No, firewalls (including Windows firewall) that use IP addresses don't distinguish between what you keep calling a "domain IP" and an actual IP. The Windows firewall will block any IP address assigned to it, including your modem, gateway or uplink. This will have no effect, however, since your computer and your modem are physically separate devices and the IP is being assigned by your ISP *to the modem*, not to your computer.

Comment: I already tryed with windows firewall and all these solution do not works because it's based on domain ip, I never request to block any domain ip, I need all domain ip allowed, i need to block some ip address assegned from my isp. I already tryed these solution posted here and for me do not work.

Answer (score 0):

For the comment-stated purpose of preventing internet access from your device, you can disable the network adapter on your device. This can be done from the command-line as well like this:

First, identify the specific network connection interface:

```
 netsh interface show interface
```

This will return something like this:

```
 Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Ethernet
 Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Wi-Fi
```

Now use the complete value under the `Interface Name` column with the following command in an elevated command prompt:

```
 netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" disable
```

To turn it back on again use:

```
 netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" enable
```

Be sure to quote the Interface Name if it includes spaces, such as `"Ethernet 3"` or `"Wireless Adapter"`.

Disabling the interface prevents all network traffic from your device through that interface, and most network traffic to your device through that interface.

However, it can still receive certain commands via system-layer controls such as IMEI or WOL. To completely disable those you need to disable the network interface within BIOS/UEFI instead of within Windows.